# merge elements of the list that have same name by column if the element length is the same

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
a<-rnorm(10, 1,1) 
b<-letters[1:10] 
ab<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)
ab

a<-rnorm(10, 1,1) 
b<-letters[1:10] 
cd<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)

list1<-list(ab,cd)
list1

### list1 done, making list with the same element names but slightly different

a<-rnorm(11, 1,1)   ###
b<-letters[1:11]    ### notice different length 
ab<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)
ab

a<-rnorm(10, 1,1) 
b<-letters[10:1]    ### notice reverse order 
cd<-cbind.data.frame(a,b)

list2<-list(ab,cd)
list1
list2
```

There are 2 lists, both of which have 2 dataframes with same names and same column names. Dimensions of the dfs, however, are different. I would like to merge these dataframes by column (b in this case) if the lengths of the dataframes are the same and end up with 3. list of dfs. If lengths are not the same, I would like to get a list (or a vector) with df names where there is difference in dimensions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop then a conditional statements to merge the data frames or add their names to a list of data frames with different lengths.

```
diff_lengths <- list()

# loop through each data frame in list1 and list2
for(i in 1:length(list1)){
  
  # check the dimensions of the current data frame
  dim1 <- dim(list1[[i]])
  dim2 <- dim(list2[[i]])
  
  # if the dimensions are the same, merge the data frames
  if(dim1[1] == dim2[1]){
    merged_df <- merge(list1[[i]], list2[[i]], by = "b")
    print(merged_df)
    
  # if the dimensions are different, add the data frame name to the list of different lengths
  } else {
    diff_lengths[[i]] <- names(list1)[i]
  }
}

# print the list of data frames with different lengths
if(length(diff_lengths) > 0){
  cat("The following data frames have different lengths:\n")
  print(diff_lengths)
} else {
  cat("All data frames have the same length.")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does a join maybe help?

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map2(list1, list2, function(x,y) {
  nrow_x = nrow(x)
  nrow_y = nrow(y)
  
  if(nrow_x == nrow_y) {
    full_join(x,y, by = "b", suffix = c("_list1","_list2"))
  } else {
   tibble(first_list_rows = nrow_x,
          second_list_rows = nrow_y) 
  }
}
)
```

**Output**:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  first_list_rows second_list_rows
            <int>            <int>
1              10               11

[[2]]
      a_list1 b    a_list2
1  -0.2133790 a  0.4248341
2   1.2334330 b  1.2870772
3   1.9252537 c -0.2991146
4   0.2112831 d  2.2372430
5  -0.4023266 e  1.1199779
6   1.7988206 f  0.4476310
7   1.2818806 g  0.9680782
8   1.1881868 h  1.5677390
9   1.5455405 i  0.9660722
10  1.7650386 j  0.4987172
```